# Mysql select row after query using data from query

Tags: mysql

Which the best method to form following query as a single query in MySql.
I have 2 following tables

Table `bid`

| user_id | row |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | silly |
| 2 | silly |
| 1 | silly |
| 1 | silly |

Table `users`

| id | username |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ElonMusk |
| 2 | VadimRog |

After query to the `bid`

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) total_bids FROM bid A GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY total_bids DESC;
```

I have a `result` such as

| user_id | total_bids |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |

So now I need to get `username` from table `users` `WHERE A.user_id = users.id;`

I have been trying many inners, outer join such as

> `SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) FROM bid A GROUP BY A.user_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC JOIN users B ON A.user_id = B.id;`

But I am on mysql error any time

What's best practice to query this in a single query and how it's looks also with foreign query?

**UPD 1.**

So I am looking for result like as

`Result`

| user_id | total_bids | username |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | ElonMusk |
| 2 | 1 | VadimRog |

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP, but does not contain any such code? Also, how would you define "best practice"?

Comment: Like Stack AI decided to suggest me php. Just some respect for AI

Comment: If your question mentions an error message then you should quote the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering each id is unique per each username in users table then a simple count would do the trick

```
SELECT u.id,count(b.user_id) as total_bids,u.username
from users u 
inner join bid b on u.id=b.user_id
group by u.id,u.username;
```

See example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/wJvnSuCT)

Comment: I spent an hour on this. You are a had man. Tu. Any advices to grow up my sql skills?

Comment: @ArthurYakovlev practice and patience . A source that I like [MySQL – Introdution](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-introdution/) and of course the [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/introduction.html). See question/answers on SO and [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.user_id, 
       COUNT(a.user_id) as total_bids, 
       b.username 
FROM bid A 
GROUP BY A.user_id 
JOIN users B ON A.user_id = B.id 
ORDER BY total_bids DESC
```

Comment: Are you sure  the given query , at least will run without errors ?

Comment: I don't think this would work.  Have to use a group-by query as sub-query and join users with that sub-query's output. Or join first and then have group-by. But above query would not work.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Yes, this query has an error `Unexpected ordering of clauses. (near "GROUP BY" at position 70)`

Comment: I do see a different error message on [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/EOPi-Pmb). it reads: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN users B ON A.user_id = B.id 
ORDER BY total_bids DESC' at line 6"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.id, COUNT(1) total_bids, users.username
FROM bid
    INNER JOIN users ON users.id = bid.user_id
GROUP BY users.id
```

This works:

```
    id  total_bids  username
------  ----------  ----------
     1           3  ElonMusk
     2           1  VadimRog
```

Join both the tables using bid.user_id & users.id
Then group by on users.id, and get a count of bid records per user.

This results in `EXPLAIN` plan like this:

```
    id  select_type  table   partitions  type    possible_keys  key         key_len  ref              rows  filtered  Extra
------  -----------  ------  ----------  ------  -------------  ----------  -------  -------------  ------  --------  -------------
     1  SIMPLE       users   (NULL)      index   PRIMARY        PRIMARY     4        (NULL)              2    100.00  (NULL)
     1  SIMPLE       bid     (NULL)      ref     fk_user_id     fk_user_id  4        test.users.id       2    100.00  Using index
```

If your MySQL does not support fields in SELECT query without adding them in GROUP BY, you have to use the following query:

```
SELECT users.id, COUNT(1) total_bids, users.username
FROM bid
    INNER JOIN users ON users.id = bid.user_id
GROUP BY users.id, users.username
```

But in doing so, the `EXPLAIN` plan changes to this:

```
    id  select_type  table   partitions  type    possible_keys  key         key_len  ref              rows  filtered  Extra
------  -----------  ------  ----------  ------  -------------  ----------  -------  -------------  ------  --------  -----------------
     1  SIMPLE       users   (NULL)      ALL     PRIMARY        (NULL)      (NULL)   (NULL)              2    100.00  Using temporary
     1  SIMPLE       bid     (NULL)      ref     fk_user_id     fk_user_id  4        test.users.id       2    100.00  Using index
```

Notice that `users` table is fully scanned.  This also depends on the number of records in the table.  If there are more records, MySQL may decide to use primary key index.

Also, you can add an index on `users.username`.
After adding an index on that column, the explain plan will be:

```
    id  select_type  table   partitions  type    possible_keys         key           key_len  ref              rows  filtered  Extra
------  -----------  ------  ----------  ------  --------------------  ------------  -------  -------------  ------  --------  ------------------------------
     1  SIMPLE       users   (NULL)      index   PRIMARY,idx_username  idx_username  203      (NULL)              2    100.00  Using index; Using temporary
     1  SIMPLE       bid     (NULL)      ref     fk_user_id            fk_user_id    4        test.users.id       2    100.00  Using index
```

So, use it the way you have to.

Comment: As far as I see, your result doesn't contain the username

Comment: Please use proper inner join syntax, comma separated join is 30+ years old syntax

Comment: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/clk2IYwa) gives error: "Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'fiddle.users.username' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"

Comment: If we have an index on `username`, then `GROUP BY username` can be added, otherwise, the query will result in a full table scan. But yes, if your version or settings don't support fields in SELECT without GROUP BY, sure it has to be added. Better add an index on the username in that case. I had checked the EXPLAIN plan for both, and this was found to be better without index on username, and it used primary key index.